# Search processes by executable name, excluding those without a TTY?

Tags: process, tty, ps

I'm trying to search for processes that have a given executable name *and* have an associated TTY.

My use-case is an attempt to identify running `abduco` client processes. Since `abduco` runs client processes with an associated TTY and server processes without one, I can use that to distinguish between them.

So far, I've come up with two approaches. I could run:

```bash
ps ao pid,comm | grep abduco
```

which by default (without adding the `x` option) only considers processes with an associated TTY.

Or I could leverage `ps -C` to select processes by executable name, rather than having to pipe to `grep` for that part. But that will include processes that have no associated TTY, and it doesn't look like `ps` provides an option to change that. So I'd have to do some post-processing to filter out processes that reported a TTY of `?`:

```bash
ps -C abduco o pid,tty
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: `ps -C name` selects processes by *process name*, not *executable name*.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I wonder if that depends on the version of `ps`? The man page on my system says "This selects the processes whose executable name is given in cmdlist."

Comment: Something like `ps -ef| awk '/abduco/ && /tty[0-9]+/'`  will do imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each system will have their own `ps` command, each with their own syntax and features.

POSIX does specify a `ps` command though with many of the options optional.

None of the options you used are standard. `ps ao` is BSD-style syntax, `ps -C` is a HP/UX option. You must be using the `ps` implementation from procps as that one did try and merge features from many different `ps` implementations.

Even with that one, I'm not aware that it can be told to report processes with a given name and with a controlling tty.

So you'd be left with post-processing:

```
ps -o pid= -o tty= -C abduco | awk '$2 != "?" {print $1}'
```

In any case, note that `-C "$string"` matches on process names, not really executable name. On Linux the process name is a string of up to 15 bytes that is an attribute of a process. It's inherited from the parent process and changed every time a process does a `execve()` system call, in which case the process name is changed to the first 15 bytes of the base name of the file path passed to `execve()` (so in that sense, that's an *executable name*), or with a `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)` call (though that's rarer).

To match on the executable whose code the process is running, you'd need to look at the `/proc/<pid>/exe` symlink (on Linux).

For instance, with `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- /proc/*/exe(e['[[ $REPLY -ef =bzip2 ]]']:h:t)
```

Would report the pids of the processes running the `bzip2` command (whose `/proc/pid/exe`, after symlink resolution is the same file as the first occurrence of a `bzip2` in `$PATH`).

And to restrict to the ones with tty:

```
() {
  print -rC1 -- /proc/$^@/exe(e['[[ $REPLY -ef =bzip2 ]]']:h:t)
} $(ps ao pid=)
```

However, since the `bzip2`, `bunzip2`, `bzcat` are all the same file, matching on executable is actually less useful than matching on process name, as that command wouldn't differentiate between processes that had invoked `bzip2` or `bunzip2` or `bzcat`.

The `bzcat` aka `bzip2` aka `bunzip2` looks at the basename of its `argv[0]` to decide whether to compress / uncompress / bzcat, so strictly speaking that should be what we would want to match on (found in `/proc/pid/cmdline` on Linux), but that's likely not worth the effort as over 99% of the time, the basename of that `argv[0]` is the same (though not truncated) as that of the executable passed to `execve()`.

Comment: This is a very thorough and informative answer. Thanks!